# WTelegramClient not reconnecting after Internet connection is lost

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I use `WTelegramClient`. The client does not reconnect after the Internet connection is restored.

Showing this:

> Connecting to 149.154.167.91:443...
> SocketException HostUnreachable (10065): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.
> Connecting to [2001:67c:4e8:f004::a]:443...
> Connecting to 149.154.167.50:443...

Answer (score 0):

**After the connection has been established**, transient connection losses should be detected and handled automatically by WTelegramClient:

- A reconnection is attempted automatically after a few seconds and pending API calls are automatically resent.
- After `MaxAutoReconnect` reconnection attempts, if the connection can still not be re-established, the `client.OnUpdate` event receives a `ReactorError` object, so you can decide what to do.

Now the log you provide doesn't give much context so I presume this happens at the very beginning of opening a session with WTelegramClient.
**In this case there is no automatic retry**, you should just catch the connection error using a `try..catch` around the `ConnectAsync` or `LoginUserIfNeeded` call, and decide what to do, when to retry the connection.